# Creating a Veloconnect server (using PHP), trying to generate xml files from xsd-schemas

Tags: php, xml, xsd

So my task is to create a working [veloconnect server](https://veloconnect.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOKUMENTAT/overview?mode=global) in a php environment.

It's not my first time creating a server like that, I don't think that'll be a problem. But I was ordered to generate the xml files for the server answers using xsd-files by veloconnect. Here's where it got hairy...

So I'm currently trying to use [goetas tools](https://github.com/goetas-webservices/xsd2php) to first generate php classes from the xsd sources and then afterwards generate objects using these classes and serialize those into the xml-files I sent out again.

I was able to do every important step with a smaller test file. Creating the yml-configuration-file for this one wasn't too hard. But in my case it's a little bit harder and I get error after error.

This is my yml-config-file...

```
# config.yml
# Linux Users: PHP Namespaces use back slash \ rather than a forward slash /
# So for destinations_php, the namespace would be TestNs\MyApp

xsd2php:
  namespaces:
    'urn:veloconnect:profile-1.3': '' 
    'urn:veloconnect:transaction-1.0': 'vct'
    'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:UnspecializedDatatypes-1.0': 'udt'
    'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CoreComponentTypes-1.0': 'cct'
    'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CoreComponentParameters-1.0': 'ccts'   
  destinations_php:
    '': objects/php
    'vct': objects/php
    'udt': objects/php
    'cct': objects/php
    'ccts': objects/php
  destinations_jms:
    '': objects/jms
    'vct': objects/jms
    'udt': objects/jms
    'cct': objects/jms
    'ccts': objects/jms
  destinations_validation:
    '': objects/validation
    'vct': objects/validation
    'udt': objects/validation
    'cct': objects/validation
    'ccts': objects/validation
    
#  aliases: # optional
#    'http://www.example.org/test/':
#      MyCustomXSDType:  'MyCustomMappedPHPType'
  naming_strategy: short # optional and default
  path_generator: psr4 # optional and default
#  known_locations: # optional
#    "http://www.example.org/test/somefile.xsd": somefile.xsd
  known_namespace_locations: # optional
    "urn:veloconnect:profile-1.3": xsd/profile-1.3.xsd
    #"urn:veloconnect:catalog-1.1": xsd/catalog-1.1.xsd
```

The xsd-file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- 
****************************************************************************** 
Copyright (C) Verbund Service und Fahrrad e. V. (2019)

Dieses Dokument, sowie Übersetzungen desselben, dürfen uneingeschränkt kopiert
und verteilt werden, vorausgesetzt, der obige Urheberrechtshinweis und diese
und die folgenden Bestimmungen sind in jeder Kopie enthalten.

Veränderungen, die über die Erfordernisse einer Übersetzung hinausgehen, sind
nur erlaubt, wenn die veränderte Version nicht den Namen veloconnect benützt
und deutliche Hinweise darauf enthält, dass diese geänderte Version auf der
veloconnect-Spezifikation beruht und inhaltliche Veränderungen vorgenommen
worden sind. Ferner ist der Urheber dieser Modifikationen zu benennen.

Zweck dieser Spezifikation ist die Implementierung von Software. Der Urheber
dieser Spezifikation weist ausdrücklich darauf hin, dass sich aus dem
Urheberrecht an dieser Spezifikation keinerlei Rechte an diesen
Implementierungen ableiten und umgekehrt aus den Implementierungen keinerlei
Ansprüche an den Urheber der Spezifikation entstehen. Insbesondere übernimmt
der Urheber dieser Spezifikation keinerlei Verantwortung für die Konformität
einer Implementierung zur veloconnect-Spezifikation und verlangt auch keine
Lizenzgebühren für die Benutzung der Spezifikation.

Der Urheber übernimmt keinerlei Gewährleistung, insbesondere nicht dafür, dass
diese Spezifikation fehlerfrei oder für einen bestimmten Zweck geeignet
ist. Die hiermit gewährten Rechte sind unwiderruflich.
****************************************************************************** 
-->


<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="urn:veloconnect:profile-1.3"
    xmlns:vct="urn:veloconnect:transaction-1.0"
    xmlns:udt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:UnspecializedDatatypes-1.0"
    targetNamespace="urn:veloconnect:profile-1.3"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xsd:import
        namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:UnspecializedDatatypes-1.0" schemaLocation="ubl/common/UBL-UnspecializedDatatypes-1.0.xsd"/>
    <xsd:import namespace="urn:veloconnect:transaction-1.0"  schemaLocation="transaction-1.0.xsd"/>

    <xsd:element name="GetProfileRequest"
        type="vct:RequestType">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Anfrage zur Ermittlung der Fähigkeiten des
                Servers.
                Jeder veloconnect-konforme Server muss diese Anfrage verarbeiten können.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="GetProfileResponse">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Antwort auf GetProfileRequest.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexContent>
                <xsd:extension base="vct:ResponseType">
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="SellerName" type="udt:TextType"
                            maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xsd:element name="Message" type="udt:TextType"
                            maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xsd:element ref="VeloconnectProfile" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:complexContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="VeloconnectProfile">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Information über die Fähigkeiten des Servers.
                Die implements-Elemente informieren über die unterstützten
                Transaktionen.
                Die property-Elemente enthalten einige für die Implementierung
                spezifischen
                Informationen als key/value-Paare.
                UnsupportedQuery und SpecialRequestReference beziehen sich auf die Belegverwaltung.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Implements" type="ImplementsType"
                    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xsd:element name="Property" type="PropertyType"
                    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xsd:element name="UnsupportedQuery" type="UnsupportedQueryType"
                    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xsd:element name="SpecialRequestReference" type="RequestReferenceType"
                    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="ImplementsType">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Information über implementierte Operationen und
                Transaktionen, sowie unterstützte Bindungen. Die Informationen über
                eine
                unterstützte Transaktion gelten für alle Operationen dieser Transaktion.
                Eine Angabe bei URI ist nur erforderlich, wenn diese Operation oder
                Transaktion unter einer anderen URL anzusprechen ist.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element name="Transaction" type="TransactionType" />
                <xsd:element name="Operation" type="OperationType" />
            </xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element name="Binding" type="BindingType" />
            <xsd:element name="URI" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0"
                maxOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="PropertyType">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Eigenschaft der Serverimplementierung.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Key" type="PropertyKeyType"/>
    <xsd:element name="Value" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="RequestReferenceType">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Spezielle Refeernzen zur Abfrage von Angeboten.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="RequestReference" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
        <xsd:element name="Description" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="OperationType">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Liste der Operationen.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:normalizedString">
            <xsd:enumeration value="GetStatus">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>GetStatus</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="Rollback">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Rollback</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="GetItemDetails">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>GetItemDetails</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="GetItemDetailsList">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>GetItemDetailsList</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="GetClassificationScheme">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>GetClassificationScheme</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="OfferQuery">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>OfferQuery</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="OfferDetails">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>OfferDetails</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="OrderConfirmationQuery">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>OrderConfirmationQuery</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="OrderConfirmationDetails">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>OrderDetails</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="DeliveryNoteQuery">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>DeliveryNoteQuery</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="DeliveryNoteDetails">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>DeliveryNoteDetails</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="InvoiceInformationQuery">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>InvoiceInformationQuery</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="InvoiceInformationDetails">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>InvoiceInformationDetails</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

  <xsd:simpleType name="TransactionType">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Liste der Transaktionen.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:normalizedString">
      <xsd:enumeration value="Order">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Order</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:enumeration>
      <xsd:enumeration value="OrderInOnlineShop">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>OrderInOnlineShop</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:enumeration>
      <xsd:enumeration value="TextSearch">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Volltextsuche</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:enumeration>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

  <xsd:simpleType name="BindingType">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Liste der Bindungen</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:normalizedString">
      <xsd:enumeration value="URL">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>URL: Anfrage per http (GET oder POST), 
Parameter als Querystring.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:enumeration>
      <xsd:enumeration value="URL-S">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>URL-S : Wie URL nur mit https.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:enumeration>
      <xsd:enumeration value="XML-POST">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>XML-POST: Request wird als XML-Dokument per http (POST) übertragen.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:enumeration>
      <xsd:enumeration value="XML-POST-S">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>XML-POST-S: Wie POST, nur mit https.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:enumeration>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

  <xsd:simpleType name="PropertyKeyType">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Mögliche Eigenschaften der Serverimplemtierung.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:normalizedString">
      <xsd:enumeration value="RecommendedRetailPrice.Netto">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>RecommendedRetailPrice.Netto: Indikator ob die empfohlenen Verkaufspreise als Nettopreise angegeben werden. 
Mögliche Werte: 
false (empfohlener VK ist brutto), 
true (empfohlener VK ist netto)</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:enumeration>
      <xsd:enumeration value="quantityUnitCode.EA">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>quantityUnitCode.EA: Indikator ob grundsätzlich nur Stück als Einheit verwendet wird. 
Mögliche Werte: false, true</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:enumeration>
      <xsd:enumeration value="OrderInOnlineShop.TransactionID">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>OrderInOnlineShop.TransactionID: Feste TransactionID für die Benutzung der OrderInOnlineShop-Transaktion. 
Muss angegeben werden, wenn diese Transaktion unterstützt wird.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:enumeration>
      <xsd:enumeration value="Order.DeliveryDate">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Order.DeliveryDate: Indikator, ob terminierte Bestellungen möglich sind.
Werte:
false : nicht möglich
order : nur ein Datum für die ganze Bestellung
line  : Datum für jede Bestellzeile individuell einstellbar</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:enumeration>
      <xsd:enumeration value="Order.Availability">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Order.Availability: Indikator, ob Informationen zur
Lieferbarkeit zur Vergügung gestellt werden.
Werte:
true : grundsätzlich Angaben zur Lieferbarkeit
false : grundsätzlich keine Angaben zu Lieferbarkeit</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:enumeration>
      <xsd:enumeration value="Order.Backlog">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Order.Backlog: Indikator, wie die Nachlieferung 
gesteuert werden kann. Mögliche Werte:
false : nicht möglich
order : Nachlieferungsverhalten nur für die Bestellung einstellbar
line  : Nachlieferungsverhalten für jede Bestellzeile individuell einstellbar</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:enumeration>
      <xsd:enumeration value="Order.BacklogDefault">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Order.BacklogDefault: Grundsätzliches Verhalten bei nicht lieferbaren Artikeln.
Werte:
false : keine Nachlieferung
true : Nachlieferung</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:enumeration>
      <xsd:enumeration value="Order.ExpectingDelivery">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Order.ExpectingDelivery: Zeitraum innerhalb dessen mit einer Lieferung zu rechnen ist; 
Wert: Zahl (Anzahl von Tagen)</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:enumeration>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="UnsupportedQueryType">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Suchparameter je Belegart.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:normalizedString">
            <xsd:enumeration value="OrderConfirmation-OrderID">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>OrderID in OrderConfirmationQueryRequest
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="DeliveryNote-OrderID">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>OrderID in DeliveryNoteQueryRequest
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="Invoice-OrderID">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>OrderID in InvoiceInformationQueryRequest
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="DeliveryNote-OrderConfirmationID">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>OrderConfirmationID in DeliveryNoteQueryRequest
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="Invoice-OrderConfirmationID">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>OrderConfirmationID in InvoiceInformationQueryRequest
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="Invoice-DeliveryNoteID">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>DeliveryNoteID in InvoiceInformationQueryRequest
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>


</xsd:schema>
```

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIMHo.png) is the error I'm getting...

```
Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\e-vendo\_veloconnect\vendor\goetas-webservices\xsd2php\src\Php\PathGenerator\Psr4PathGenerator.php on line 14
```

I'm afraid I really need some help to get this done, I've already been debugging these tools for days now. Am I missing anything? There isn't really any helpful documentation or threads on the internet about this. I'm grateful for every tip, alternative solutions or tools to tackle this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... finally found the answer myself. The first namespace should be veloconnect, after that I just needed to add the missing namespaces. so a working yml-file now looks like that if someone has the same problem in the future...

```
# config.yml
# Linux Users: PHP Namespaces use back slash \ rather than a forward slash /
# So for destinations_php, the namespace would be TestNs\MyApp

xsd2php:
  namespaces:
    'urn:veloconnect:profile-1.3': 'veloconnect' 
    'urn:veloconnect:transaction-1.0': 'vct'
    'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:UnspecializedDatatypes-1.0': 'udt'
    'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CoreComponentTypes-1.0': 'cct'
    'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CoreComponentParameters-1.0': 'ccts'   
  destinations_php:
    'veloconnect': objects/php
    'vct': objects/php
    'udt': objects/php
    'cct': objects/php
    'ccts': objects/php
  destinations_jms:
    'veloconnect': objects/jms
    'vct': objects/jms
    'udt': objects/jms
    'cct': objects/jms
    'ccts': objects/jms
  destinations_validation:
    'veloconnect': objects/validation
    'vct': objects/validation
    'udt': objects/validation
    'cct': objects/validation
    'ccts': objects/validation
    
#  aliases: # optional
#    'http://www.example.org/test/':
#      MyCustomXSDType:  'MyCustomMappedPHPType'
  naming_strategy: short # optional and default
  path_generator: psr4 # optional and default
#  known_locations: # optional
#    "http://www.example.org/test/somefile.xsd": somefile.xsd
  known_namespace_locations: # optional
    "urn:veloconnect:profile-1.3": xsd/profile-1.3.xsd
    #"urn:veloconnect:catalog-1.1": xsd/catalog-1.1.xsd
```